# How to make class-validator validate an object whose type is an intersection type

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, class-validator

There's a method that accepts an intersection of a few DTOs:

```
export type RegisterUserDto = RegisterCommonUserDto
                            & RegisterLocationProviderDto
                            & RegisterFighterDto;
```

The method looks like that:

```
    @Post('register')
    public async registerUser(@Body() registerUserDto: RegisterUserDto): Promise<any> {
        // method code
    }
```

The controller itself is decorated with `@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true, forbidNonWhitelisted: true }))`

So when a DTO is a class the validation works, but now it's a type and the class-validator just fails to react to incorrect data, I mean all its decorators like `@IsEmail()`, `@IsPhoneNumber()` etc just don't work.

What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this issue with the help of this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mixer implementing multiple inheritance. So now my `RegisterUserDto` looks like this.

```
export class RegisterUserDto extends Mixin(RegisterCommonUserDto, RegisterLocationProviderDto, RegisterFighterDto) {}
```

However I would appreciate other solutions.